# How to create background for NSView when using storyboards with OS X

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift, nsview

I know how I may be able to do this programmatically. I know that when creating storyboards for iOS it's very easy and is right there in the attributes inspector. However when creating storyboards for OS X, I don't see it for any of my view controllers or the view underneath it in Xcode 6.1.1

How can I change the background of the view without having to create a view controller associated with it. My application has a lot of views that are simple, but the background changes colour from one view to the next.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't need a new viewController to change the background of an NSView.  If you aren't subclassing NSView, then you can simply call:

```
myView.wantsLayer = true
myView.layer!.backgroundColor = CGColorGetConstantColor(kCGColorBlack)
```

I'm not sure if you can do it strictly in the storyboard, though you can likely set the wantsLayer = true in storyboard using the User Defined Runtime Attributes.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this helped. I subclassed NSView instead and used code from here: https://github.com/benzguo/demosthenes/blob/master/demosthenes/Categories/NSView.swift

Answer (score 10):

Here is another way to achieve the same effect.

Add **`NSBox`** under your NSView and adjust NSBox's frame as the same with the NSView.

Change Title position to None, Box type to **Custom**, Border Type to **None**

This is the screenshot:

[image]

And than add your NSView, NSButton, NSTextField or whatever as a subview of NSBox.

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can change a `NSView`'s background color in the storyboard if you subclass `NSView` and assign the subclass to your view:

[image]

[image]

Using this subclass implementation:

```swift
import Cocoa

class ViewWithBackgroundColor : NSView {
    @IBInspectable var backgroundColor: NSColor? {
        get {
            guard let layer = layer, backgroundColor = layer.backgroundColor else { return nil }
            return NSColor(CGColor: backgroundColor)
        }

        set {
            wantsLayer = true
            layer?.backgroundColor = newValue?.CGColor
        }
    }

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}
```

The background color isn't shown at design time but at run-time.

Maybe somebody got an idea how to also update the view at design time (preferably without overriding the draw method).